# Exponential function with addition

Tags: c

I am trying to create exponential function with for loop. so if num1 is 10, and num2 is 2

```
for (i = 0; i < num1; i++)
      sum = sum + num2;
for (i = 0; i < num2 ; i++)
      sum2 = sum + sum2;
```

Comment: Homework? Looks like it is :)

Comment: To confirm, do you want to calculate *exponentiation* (i.e. *a* to the power of *b*), or do you want to calculate the *exponential function* (i.e. *e* to the power of *a*)?

Comment: power of b so a^b....but using addition. i am having trouble putting it into a for loop tho

Answer (score 6):

Repeated addition mimics multiplication.
Repeated multiplication mimics exponentiation.

Just make two loops, one inside another: the inner loop to mimic multiplication and the outer loop to mimic exponentioation.

---

EDIT: here's a recursive method. Transforming it into a couple loops shouldn't be too difficult. [Tested on codepad](http://codepad.org/HG6am8vD).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int mul(int b, int e) {
  if (e == 0) return 0;
  if (e == 1) return b;
  return b + mul(b, e - 1); /* additions only */
}

int expo(int b, int e) {
  if (e == 0) return 1;
  if (e == 1) return b;
  return mul(b, expo(b, e-1));
}

int main(void) {
  printf("3^0 is %d\n", expo(3, 0));
  printf("3^1 is %d\n", expo(3, 1));
  printf("3^2 is %d\n", expo(3, 2));
  printf("3^3 is %d\n", expo(3, 3));
  printf("3^4 is %d\n", expo(3, 4));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: so
for(i = 0; i <= num2 ; i ++){
        sum = sum + num2;
for (i = 0; i <= num1 ; i++){
        sum2 = sum + num1;

Comment: how do u make a loop to mimic expnentioation?

Comment: exponentiation in a loop: `val = 1; for (k = 0; k < exponent; k++) { val *= base; }` and now `val` has `base ^ exponent`. When doing the exercise you must pay attention to the base which is going to be different every time through the loop. *converting the recursive functions was a little tougher than I expected*

Comment: okay so for the value of the base can i do value = value + base? will that work because i am trying to do this with addition

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like me using /, implement your FPU yourself.

Something like this?

```
double power(int x, int p){
    if(p==0)
        return 1.0;

    double res = x;
    for(int i=1 ; i<p ; ++i)
        res += x;

    return res;
}

long mul(long a, long b){
    if(a==0 || b==0)
        return 0;

    long res = 0;
    for(int i=0 ; i<a ; ++i){
        res += b;
    }
    return res;
}

long fac(long x){
    if(x==0)
        return 1;
    return mul(fac(x-1),x);
}

double exponential(int x, int c) 
{
    double res = 0.0;
    for(int i=0; i<=c;++i)
        res += power(x)/(double)fac(i);
    return res;
}
```

Not tested, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function for definition of formula.

Comment: I am trying to do that with addition only tho

Comment: You have low rep, so I'm not going to downvote you as I assume you don't know the customs, but you really should not give full code to a homework quesition.

Comment: After clarification, it appears that the OP doesn't want *exponentiation*, he/she simply wants *power*.

Comment: anyone know how to do that with addition?